# SAML Authentication from SP

Tags: asp.net, saml-2.0, adfs, acs

I am learning SAML based claims authentication with ADFS. Instead of taking the user to IDP's login page and then requesting the User to enter her credentials, Is it possible to get the user's credentials in SP pass it on to IdP to get it verified there and return back to SP with a SAML token.

This is purely experimental and I would like to try this to avoid user entering credentials in IdP login page rather take her credentials in SP get it validated from IdP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do this then you will loose benefits such as SSO for other relying parties.

However AD FS does have an endpoint, which you can call from a WCF client that accepts a username and password and gives you back a SAML security token (if the relying party is set up for a SAML token)

[image]

Comment: How about doing this with ACS ?